# Create a substring from an html string data

Tags: javascript

I have a dynamic html string fetched from api response.
A sample response would be as follows

```
  {
  "success": true,
  "message": "Success",
  "response": {
    "document": {
      "id": "03cb14d6-46d3-11e8-acb9-408d5ce49fe0",
      "name": "Letter",
      "html_content": "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n<head>\n\t<meta charset=\"UTF-8\">\n\t<title>HR3-Offer Letter</title>\n\t<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">\n\t<style>\n\t\tbody {\n\t\t\tfont-family: \"Times New Roman\", Times, serif;\n\t\t\tfont-size: 16px;\n\t\t\ttext-align: left;\n\t\t\tline-height: 1.2;\n\t\t}\n\t\th1,\n\t\th2,\n\t\th3,\n\t\th4, h5, h6 {\n\t\t\tfont-weight: normal;\n\t\t\tmargin-top: 0;\n\t\t}\n\t\t#content-wrap {\n\t\t\tbackground: #fff;\n\t\t\tpadding: 50px;\n\t\t}\n\t\t.txt-center {\n\t\t\ttext-align: center;\n\t\t}\n\t\t.txt-upper {\n\t\t\ttext-transform: uppercase;\n\t\t}\n\t\th1 {\n\t\t\tmargin-bottom: 10px;\n\t\t\tfont-size: 23px;\n\t\t}\n\t\tp {\n\t\t\tmargin-bottom: 30px;\n\t\t}\n\t\t.contact-person {\n\t\t\tborder-top: 1px solid #000;\n\t\t\tpadding-top: 40px;\n\t\t\tmargin-bottom: 80px;\n\t\t\twidth: 70%;\n\t\t}\n\t\t.contact-person p {\n\t\t\tmargin: 5px 0 0 0;\n\t\t}\n\t\t.offer-accepted {\n\t\t\tmargin-bottom: 50px;\n\t\t}\n\t\t.offer {\n\t\t\tmargin-right: 15px;\n\t\t}\n\t\t.signature-date .label,\n\t\t.signature-date .value {\n\t\t\tdisplay: inline-block;\n\t\t\twidth: 180px;\n\t\t}\n\t\t.signature-date .label {\n\t\t\twidth: 177px;\n\t\t}\n\t\t.signature-date .value {\n\t\t\tborder-bottom: 1px solid #000;\n\t\t}\n\t\t.highlighter {\n\t\t\tbackground: #ffff00;\n\t\t}\n\t</style>\n</head>\n<body>\n\t<div id=\"content-wrap\">\n\t\t<h1 class=\"txt-center txt-upper\"><%= COMPANY %></h1></body>\n</html>"
    }
  }
}
```

res.html_content is having the html string.

I need to create a substring which contains all the data till the body tag.

The output should be as follows.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n<head>\n\t<meta charset=\"UTF-8\">\n\t<title>HR3-Offer Letter</title>\n\t<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">\n\t<style>\n\t\tbody {\n\t\t\tfont-family: \"Times New Roman\", Times, serif;\n\t\t\tfont-size: 16px;\n\t\t\ttext-align: left;\n\t\t\tline-height: 1.2;\n\t\t}\n\t\th1,\n\t\th2,\n\t\th3,\n\t\th4, h5, h6 {\n\t\t\tfont-weight: normal;\n\t\t\tmargin-top: 0;\n\t\t}\n\t\t#content-wrap {\n\t\t\tbackground: #fff;\n\t\t\tpadding: 50px;\n\t\t}\n\t\t.txt-center {\n\t\t\ttext-align: center;\n\t\t}\n\t\t.txt-upper {\n\t\t\ttext-transform: uppercase;\n\t\t}\n\t\th1 {\n\t\t\tmargin-bottom: 10px;\n\t\t\tfont-size: 23px;\n\t\t}\n\t\tp {\n\t\t\tmargin-bottom: 30px;\n\t\t}\n\t\t.contact-person {\n\t\t\tborder-top: 1px solid #000;\n\t\t\tpadding-top: 40px;\n\t\t\tmargin-bottom: 80px;\n\t\t\twidth: 70%;\n\t\t}\n\t\t.contact-person p {\n\t\t\tmargin: 5px 0 0 0;\n\t\t}\n\t\t.offer-accepted {\n\t\t\tmargin-bottom: 50px;\n\t\t}\n\t\t.offer {\n\t\t\tmargin-right: 15px;\n\t\t}\n\t\t.signature-date .label,\n\t\t.signature-date .value {\n\t\t\tdisplay: inline-block;\n\t\t\twidth: 180px;\n\t\t}\n\t\t.signature-date .label {\n\t\t\twidth: 177px;\n\t\t}\n\t\t.signature-date .value {\n\t\t\tborder-bottom: 1px solid #000;\n\t\t}\n\t\t.highlighter {\n\t\t\tbackground: #ffff00;\n\t\t}\n\t</style>\n</head>\n
```

That is, the input string contains doctype, title, head and body tags and the output string should not contain body tag and the rest of string.

Any idea on how to implement this?

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use regex is the best way in this case:

```js
var obj =  {
  "success": true,
  "message": "Success",
  "response": {
    "document": {
      "id": "03cb14d6-46d3-11e8-acb9-408d5ce49fe0",
      "name": "Letter",
      "html_content": "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n<head>\n\t<meta charset=\"UTF-8\">\n\t<title>HR3-Offer Letter</title>\n\t<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">\n\t<style>\n\t\tbody {\n\t\t\tfont-family: \"Times New Roman\", Times, serif;\n\t\t\tfont-size: 16px;\n\t\t\ttext-align: left;\n\t\t\tline-height: 1.2;\n\t\t}\n\t\th1,\n\t\th2,\n\t\th3,\n\t\th4, h5, h6 {\n\t\t\tfont-weight: normal;\n\t\t\tmargin-top: 0;\n\t\t}\n\t\t#content-wrap {\n\t\t\tbackground: #fff;\n\t\t\tpadding: 50px;\n\t\t}\n\t\t.txt-center {\n\t\t\ttext-align: center;\n\t\t}\n\t\t.txt-upper {\n\t\t\ttext-transform: uppercase;\n\t\t}\n\t\th1 {\n\t\t\tmargin-bottom: 10px;\n\t\t\tfont-size: 23px;\n\t\t}\n\t\tp {\n\t\t\tmargin-bottom: 30px;\n\t\t}\n\t\t.contact-person {\n\t\t\tborder-top: 1px solid #000;\n\t\t\tpadding-top: 40px;\n\t\t\tmargin-bottom: 80px;\n\t\t\twidth: 70%;\n\t\t}\n\t\t.contact-person p {\n\t\t\tmargin: 5px 0 0 0;\n\t\t}\n\t\t.offer-accepted {\n\t\t\tmargin-bottom: 50px;\n\t\t}\n\t\t.offer {\n\t\t\tmargin-right: 15px;\n\t\t}\n\t\t.signature-date .label,\n\t\t.signature-date .value {\n\t\t\tdisplay: inline-block;\n\t\t\twidth: 180px;\n\t\t}\n\t\t.signature-date .label {\n\t\t\twidth: 177px;\n\t\t}\n\t\t.signature-date .value {\n\t\t\tborder-bottom: 1px solid #000;\n\t\t}\n\t\t.highlighter {\n\t\t\tbackground: #ffff00;\n\t\t}\n\t</style>\n</head>\n<body>\n\t<div id=\"content-wrap\">\n\t\t<h1 class=\"txt-center txt-upper\"><%= COMPANY %></h1></body>\n</html>"
    }
  }
};
var regex_head = /(.|\n)+?\<\/head\>/;
var result = obj['response']['document']['html_content'].match(regex_head);
console.log(result[0]);
```